# double click required to insert into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

this might be a really simple solution but I really can't figure it out. if i insert into my database I have to press the insert button twice for it to work.. My guess is that it has to do with my using of 2 forms in one file or just because I did it all in one file. please help me.

thanks

code:

```
<?php
/*require "link.php";*/
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">--> <!-- verwijzing naar je css -->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <header>
    </header>
    <article>
        <div id="cards">
            <?php 
            $host = "localhost";
            $user = "root";
            $pwd = "";
            $db_name = "flashcards";
            $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db_name)or die("cannot connect");
            $array = array();
            $IDarray = array();

            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY ID ASC ") or die(mysqli_error($link)); 
            echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'><table border='1'>";
            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                echo "<tr id='".$rows['ID']."'><td>".$rows['Question']."</td><td><input type='text' name='Answer[]' id='V".$rows['ID']."'></input></td></tr>";
                $array[] = $rows["Answer"];
                $IDarray[] = $rows["ID"];
            }  
            echo "</table><input type='submit' name='submit'></input></form>";

            $i = 0;
            $count = sizeof($IDarray);
            if(!empty($_POST['Answer']))
            { 
                foreach($_POST['Answer'] as $answer)
                {
                    if (isset($_POST['Answer'])) {
                        if ($answer == $array[$i])
                        {
                            echo "<script>document.getElementById('".$IDarray[$i]."').style.background='green'; document.getElementById('V".$IDarray[$i]."').value='".$array[$i]."'</script>";
                        }
                        elseif ($answer !== $array[$i])
                        {
                            echo "<script>document.getElementById('".$IDarray[$i]."').style.background='red'; document.getElementById('V".$IDarray[$i]."').value='".$answer."'</script>";
                            $count = $count-1;
                        }
                        $i ++;
                    }
                }echo $count." van de ".sizeof($IDarray)." goed";
                if ($count == sizeof($IDarray))
                {
                    header('Location: http://localhost:1336/php3/');
                }
            }

            echo "</br></br>insert";
            echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'><table border='1'>";
            echo "<tr><td>vraag</td><td><input type='text' name='vraag'></input></td><td>antwoord</td><td><input type='text' name='antwoord'></input></td></tr>";
            echo "</table><input type='submit' name='submitinsert' value='insert'></input></form>";

            if ($_POST['vraag'] != "") {
                $vraag = $_POST['vraag'];
                $antwoord = $_POST['antwoord'];
                mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO questions (Question, Answer) VALUES (".$vraag.",".$antwoord.");") or die(mysqli_error($link)); 
            }
            ?> 
        </div>
    </article>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: oh and the echo with "are you sure?" really doesnt mean anything. I just put it there when I was trying to solve this issue.

Comment: You _can_ edit your own questions, you know... I've removed the `echo` for you, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're processing the form submission in the same script as the one that *generates* the form. Couple that to the fact that you *firsT* query the DB, generate a form with what you've already stored, and *then* add whatever data the user may have posted, you'll never see the data you've added show up the first time 'round you submit the form.
Either move the insert queries to the top (before generating the form), or *separate concerns*

Let me show you what I mean:

```
//don't OR DIE
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY ID ASC ") or die(mysqli_error($link));
echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'><table border='1'>";
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{//build form here
}
/*
CODE HERE
*/
if ($_POST['vraag'] != "") {
    //insert here, after form is generated
}
```

So the data you query cannot, yet, contain the submitted form data.
There are some other issues with the code, though, like `or die`: don't do that. Be consistent with your coding style (allman brackets + K&R in the same script is messy). Properly indent your code and this:

```
if ($_POST['vraag'] != "") {
}
```

should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['vraag'])) {
}
```

You're comparing a key of an array that *may not exist* to an empty string, whereas you *should* check if that array key exists. Use `isset`.

I could go on a bit, but I'll leave it at that for now. Just one more thing: again -> separrate concerns! The presentation layer (the output: HTML and such) ***should not*** contain DB connection stuff. That should be done elsewhere.
Process your form either asynchronously (as whatever is submitted gets added to the table that is already there) using AJAX, or at least, use a separate script. Having 1 script doing all the work will soon leave you crying over a mess of spaghetti code

Comment: thanks for the comment, I usually don't put database stuff on this place but this time I was just messing around and didnt feel like creating multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

Its not submitting twice, actually its not loading the data after insertion,

Try adding

```
        if ($_POST['vraag'] != "") {
            $vraag = $_POST['vraag'];
            $antwoord = $_POST['antwoord'];
            echo "are you sure?";
            mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO questions (Question, Answer) VALUES (".$vraag.",".$antwoord.");") or die(mysqli_error($link)); 
        }
```

before

```
  $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY ID ASC ") or   
  die(mysqli_error($link));
```

this will select your records after the current record is saved.